# Enum with dynamic method parameters

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum defined with some messages, but these messages have `%s` placeholders. For example:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    SUCCESS ("Processed successfully", Arrays.asList()),
    ERROR ("Error occurred, reason : %s", Arrays.asList("static reason"));

    private String msg;
    private Object[] params;

    private MyEnum(String msg, Object... params) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return String.format(this.msg, this.params); 
    }
}
```

So, here I am able to pass static reason for the `ERROR` enum value. I want clients to pass the error reason and get the generate enum value from getMessage() method.

I thought of achieving this by passing `params` in the `getMessage` method instead -

```
public String getMessage(String... params) {
    return String.format(this.msg, params);
}
```

Is there any better option than doing this? I want my enum to return dynamically generated messages based on `params`.

Comment: I think, your first version would not work the way you want. Since you have to supply the parameters to the constructor, you could just write the formatted text. Remove "params" as parameter and member and use your getMessage method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do anything "dynamic" with the constructor:  `SUCCESS` and `ENUM` are static references that will each be initialized to point to a new MyEnum instance when the class is loaded.  The constructor will be called once each, and then never again during the lifetime of the program.

> I thought of achieving this by passing params in the getMessage method instead... Is there any better option than doing this?

No better way that I can think of.